# ASP.Net Webforms: Can a RequiredFieldValidator be listened to? (Event)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, dom-events

Basically is there a way to hook into when a `RequiredFieldValidator` does what it does?  Like `validator.ValidationCompleted` ?

Normally for script controls, you can create an expose events so that you can listen to them from other controls, and I was asked if this is possible for the build in validation controls in asp.net but couldn't come up with a good way to do this.  I was hoping that there is something built in that fires after a validator has completed it's task that can be captured client side.

Answer (score 0):

Validators tend to operate client-side by default (EnabledClientScript defaults to True), but if you choose to push them server-side you simply need to look at the IsValid property of the Page to see if the validators were successful.  You can look validator-by-validator server-side to determine which validators failed by iterating through the Page.Validators collection and checking each Validator for IsValid.  If you wish you could change the way client-side validation is handled through this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

You'll have to use a CustomValidator for client-side script you want to run when validation occurs.  See the "ClientValidationFunction" property.  Other options include 3rd party validation controls, or rolling your own.